# Cant understand this stack trace

Tags: android

I have a published app and received a stack trace from a crash:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token   
 android.os.BinderProxy@4051d698 is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:535)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:203)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:117)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
at com.mytaxicontrol.MyTaxiControlActivity$executeGEO.void onPreExecute()(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
at com.mytaxicontrol.MyTaxiControlActivity$37.void run()(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:3743)
at com.mytaxicontrol.MyTaxiControlActivity.void geo()(Unknown Source)
```

Looks like a progress Dialog can't be shown. Here's the relevant code:

```
public void onPreExecute() {
        if(isGeoRunning)return; 

        if (loading == null || !loading.isShowing())
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(co, "",
                    "Retrieving Geolocation...", true);
    }
```

Note that co=this and has been initialized in onCreate()
What is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably when the user does "BACK" before your *Asynctask* has finished.

Comment: can I do anything about this?

Comment: yea, check if the activity is not null before trying to add the window, or add a try ... catch block around

Comment: the try ... catch should work ;) It may be because the user leaves the app or goes to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token
>    android.os.BinderProxy@4051d698 is not valid; is your activity running?

Your app was probably just recreated because screen rotated or user pressed home / back or something similar happened. So your app was actually not running.

It's a bit tricky to have UI + AsyncTasks that don't break with activity lifecycle but there are some options.

e.g.: 
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e1d5b8f8a3142892

Basically you need to make sure that AsyncTask does not touch the UI while there is no UI.